# Angular components with fixed full width elements not showing correctly

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css

I'm still trying to replicate a famous chat app just for exercise. Everything is almost done, but I'm struggling with this last thing.
I have a lot of nested components, and they look perfectly if I try to show them separately, but when I put them together they mess up everything.
Here is my situation:
[Main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKN31.jpg)

This is composed by 2 components, app-chat-window:

```
<div class="flex flex-col w-[100vw]">
<app-header class="fixed w-[100%]"></app-header>
<app-messages class="bg-dark-secondary pb-[48px] pt-[57px]"></app-messages>
<app-message-editor class="fixed w-[100%] bottom-0"></app-message-editor>
```

and app-side:

```
<div class="flex max-w-full">
<app-nav-bar class="fixed"></app-nav-bar>
<app-chat-dashboard class="flex-grow ml-16"></app-chat-dashboard>
```

Now app-side looks perfect, but app-chat-window doesn't fit inside its space.
Here is the code for the app-header:

```
<div class="flex bg-dark-secondary p-2 pl-6 border-b border-l border-dark-secondary-focus text-medium">
<img src="./assets/placeholder.png" alt="Name" class="size-10 rounded-full">
<p class="p-2 flex-1">Nome</p>
<fa-icon [icon]="faVideoCall" size="lg" class="p-2 mx-1 rounded-lg hover:bg-dark-secondary-focus"></fa-icon>
<fa-icon [icon]="faCall" size="lg" class="p-2 mx-1 rounded-lg hover:bg-dark-secondary-focus"></fa-icon>
<fa-icon [icon]="faSearch" size="lg" class="p-2 mx-1 rounded-lg hover:bg-dark-secondary-focus"></fa-icon>
```

and for the app-message-editor:

```
<div class="flex bg-dark-secondary text-medium border-t border-b border-dark-secondary-focus">
<fa-icon [icon]="faPlus" size="xl" class="p-3 shrink-0"></fa-icon>
<div class="flex flex-row-reverse flex-1 items-center relative">
    <div class="flex absolute -translate-x-4">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faSticker" class="text-medium mx-1.5" size="lg"></fa-icon>
        <fa-icon [icon]="faEmoji" class="text-medium mx-1.5" size="lg"></fa-icon>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="h-8 mx-2 pl-3 bg-dark-secondary-focus rounded-full flex-1 border text-light-basic border-medium text-sm">
</div>
```

and for the app-messages:

```
<div class="flex flex-col">
<app-message *ngFor="let message of chat?.messages; index as i" [message]="message" [sent]="message.sender === 'Andrea'"></app-message>
```

I don't understand what it's wrong, because as I said everything looks great alone.